# Рисовать на подгруженном изображении

Tags: java, android

Создаю приложение для рисования. На обычном пустом канвасе отлично рисует, но когда я хочу подрузить изображение из галереи при нажатии я продолжаю рисовать под картинкой. Что делать?
Код DrawView класса:

```
public DrawView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        //the below methods smoothens the drawings of the user
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        //0xff=255 in decimal
        mPaint.setAlpha(0xff);
        Log.d(TAG, "DrawView created");
    }

    //this method instantiate the bitmap and object
    public void init(int height, int width) {

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

        //set an initial color of the brush
        currentColor = Color.RED;
        //set an initial brush size
        strokeWidth = 20;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        //DEFAULT color of the canvas
        int backgroundColor = Color.WHITE;
        mCanvas.drawColor(backgroundColor);

        //now, we iterate over the list of paths and draw each path on the canvas
        for (Stroke fp : paths) {
            mPaint.setColor(fp.color);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(fp.strokeWidth);

            mCanvas.drawPath(fp.path, mPaint);
        }
//        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.restore();
    }



     public Bitmap save() {
        return mBitmap;
    }


    protected void setImageUri(Uri uri) {
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
            float aspecRatio = (float) bitmap.getHeight() / (float) bitmap.getWidth();
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            int mImageWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
            int mImageHeight = Math.round(mImageWidth * aspecRatio);
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, mImageWidth, mImageHeight, false);
            invalidate();
            requestLayout();
            mCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mImageWidth, mImageHeight, null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "1", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
MainActivity:

private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher;

someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                result -> {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        // There are no request codes
                        Intent data = result.getData();
                        if (data != null) {

                            InputStream inputStream;
                            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

                            try {
                                inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                                Log.d(TAG, image + " ");
                                Log.d(TAG, drawView + " ");
                                Uri imageUri = drawView.getImageUri(MainActivity.this, image);
                                Log.d(INSERT_IMAGE, "Image inserted");
                                drawView.setImageUri(imageUri);
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Попробуйте установить у bitmap свойство setZ

Comment: Вы же при загрузке картинки пересоздаете битмап, а канва на которой рисуете остается прежней, вот и расхождение. Там у вам напутано, канва от битмапа, который переопределяется, но отрисовывается на канве, которая от старого бимапа, которого по сути уже и нет :)

Comment: и как же убрать расхождение?